# Google Apps Script Bulk Set Properties

Tags: properties, google-apps-script

Another GAS question. I read the documentation on [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties#setProperties%28Object%29) and bulk-setting properties, as well as (again) the documentation on [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices). However, I'm not familiar with Javascript, and still new to GAS, and I keep running over the rate limit for API calls as a result.

Basically, I would like to 'get' all these properties from the Spreadsheet, put them in an Array or Object or something, then bulk set all of them. I have the keys and values correct, I just don't know how to temp store them in a JS Object or Array or some data type that will be accepted by the `setProperties(Object)` method.

Here is the current code (horrendous `Sleep` timer is the only thing that is working...):

```
function setSubsequentProperties(propertyRange, sheet) {

  // Get the other Library Properties based on the new Range values.
  // propertyRange is the 2-column 1-row Range for the key/value pairs
  var tableRange = ScriptProperties.getProperty(propertyRange);
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Create a 'properties' Object for bulk-setting to prevent overusing API calls
  //var properties = new Array(data.length);

  // Set a new Script Property for each row
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var propertyKey = row[0];
    var propertyValue = row[1];

    // var myObject = allMyPropertiesInOneObject

    ScriptProperties.setProperty(propertyKey, propertyValue);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
// setProperties(myObject);
}
```

How might I go about adding `propertyKey` and `propertyValue` to an Object to bulk set them all at once? The pseudo-idea is commented out in the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you are new to Javascript, I assume you are new to [JSON](http://json.org/) as well. There is indeed a `ScriptProperties.setProperties()` method which takes a JSON object as argument.

Modifying just the setProperty() bit of your code, here is what you can do

```
function setSubsequentProperties(propertyRange, sheet) {

  // Get the other Library Properties based on the new Range values.
  // propertyRange is the 2-column 1-row Range for the key/value pairs
  var tableRange = ScriptProperties.getProperty(propertyRange);
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Create a 'properties' Object for bulk-setting to prevent overusing API calls
  //var properties = new Array(data.length);

  // Set a new Script Property for each row
  var myObject  = {} ;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var propertyKey = row[0];
    var propertyValue = row[1];

    // var myObject = allMyPropertiesInOneObject
    myObject[propertyKey] = propertyValue; 

  }
  ScriptProperties.setProperties(myObject);
}
```

Comment: That is some damn brilliantly simple documentation! I took a look at it, understand Javascript a bit more, and also got the JSON object setting the bulk parameters to work! Srik you're amazing, to say the least. I appreciate all the help you've given me on my GAS problems :) My stupid functions with 137 properties to set took 3 minutes to run before, now it takes 10 seconds: superb :D

Comment: Right sorry, I forgot to do that. Done now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this answer, Google has deprecated ScriptProperties and replaced it with the PropertiesService. You can solve the same problem using setProperties() on a Properties object, except you have to choose which kind of store you want using a call to PropertiesService first:

```js
var myObject  = {} ;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var propertyKey = row[0];
    var propertyValue = row[1];
    myObject[propertyKey] = propertyValue; 
  }

var myProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // or getUserProperties() or getDocumentProperties()
myProperties.setProperties(myObject);
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperties(Object)) for details. Note: this only seems to work for simple key/value pairs. When I try to set and get more complex JSON objects, with keys set to arrays of values, I can retrieve the object but not the values inside it. I can't use JSON.parse() on it successfully, either. I'll post again if I can figure it out.